# How can I make Dir[] and Dir.foreach return results in deterministic order?

Tags: ruby, testing, filesystems

I'm trying to glob a directory, with `Dir[]` and/or with `Dir.foreach`:

```rb
files = Dir["#{options[:dir]}/**/*"].reject { |file| File.directory?(file) }
puts files.map{|filename| filename.join("\n")
```

and:

```
def print_tree(dir = ".", nesting = 0)
  Dir.foreach(dir) do |entry|
    next if entry =~ /^\.{1,2}/ # Ignore ".", "..", or hidden files
    puts "| " * nesting + "|-- #{entry}"
    if File.stat(d = "#{dir}#{File::SEPARATOR}#{entry}").directory?
      print_tree(d, nesting + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test this with [Cucumber and Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba). Here's what's in my `listing_files.feature`:

```
When I run `poet ls`
Then the output should contain exactly:
"""
foo/bar/conf1
foo/conf2.disabled

"""
```

and:

```
Then the output should contain exactly:
"""
|-- foo
| |-- bar
| | |-- conf1
| |-- conf2.disabled

"""
```

Tests on my local machine work (OSX) fine, but I get this failure on Travis:

```
expected: "foo/bar/conf1\nfoo/conf2.disabled\n"
got: "foo/conf2.disabled\nfoo/bar/conf1\n" (using ==)
```

Obviously, the order in which results are returned is not the same on all systems. This is [documented behavior](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) for 1.9.3 and 2.0:

> Note that case sensitivity depends on your system (so File::FNM_CASEFOLD is ignored),
>   as does the order in which the results are returned.

This makes testing directory listing a nightmare though. Can I somehow force the order? Or if not, is there a best practice to test things like this integratively?

Comment: please give us the code you are using. Only output is not sufficient.

Comment: @RubyLovely You're absolutely right, I updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always sort the results of the `Dir[]` call before returning them:

```
def print_tree(dir = ".", nesting = 0)
  Dir.entries(dir).sort.each do |entry|
    # the rest is the same...
  end
end
```

Or, if you have two arrays of directory listings, sort each in the test before comparing them.

Also, if you're using RSpec you can expect on array contents rather than order/contents by using the `=~` operator:

```
arr1 = Dir['*.whatever']
arr2 = some_method_that_gets_the_dir_listing()
arr2.should =~ arr1
```

In Test::Unit, the same can be done using `assert_same_elements`

Comment: I'm trying to test this integratively with Cucumber+Aruba. I've updated the question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think it's important to be consistent with your output across systems, so I'd recommend sorting your directory output before you start building the `print_tree` output, like I suggest first -- I updated my answer to show you.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! Good point with the consistent output across systems. I realize now: This is not about the test, but more about the software in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order you can always use the `include` matcher with a splat to unpack your array

```
[1,2,3,4,5].should include(*[5,2,4,1,3])
```

Comment: I'm trying to test this integratively with Cucumber+Aruba. I've updated the question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.